# Rest API: Why is object doesn't findable in 'create' function?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For example, here is my all data : [IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqmlQ.png)

My viewset :

```
class CardCheckViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CardCheckSerializer
    queryset = CardCheck.objects.all()

    def create(self, request):
        for obj in CardCheck.objects.all():
            print(obj)

        return super().create(request)
```

And here is the data after I post something in it: [IMG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZMtU.png)

There should be 4 objects but this is what I got printed :

```
CardCheck object (30)
CardCheck object (34)
CardCheck object (44)
```

There is not the posted data as you see. Why is that data doesnt appears in here? What can I do about it?

Comment: you print the objects before creating the new object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to print the `CardCheck` items before adding a new one. This way should work:

```py
class CardCheckViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CardCheckSerializer
    queryset = CardCheck.objects.all()

    def create(self, request):
        new_obj = super().create(request)
        for obj in CardCheck.objects.all():
            print(obj)

        return new_obj
```